# .toggle is animating my anchor tag instead of using it as a click

Tags: jquery, toggle

I know that .toggle can perform two different things, if you provide two functions it supposed to provide a toggle button click on and off sort of but my code is making the animation happen right away and the anchor tag just dissapears

html

```
<nav class="mainNav">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="home"><a href="#">home</a></li>
                        <li class="work"><a href="#">work</a></li>
                        <li class="blog"><a href="#">blog</a></li>
                        <li class="contact"><a href="#">contact</a></li>

                    </ul>
                    <a href="#" id="toggle">HI</a>
                </nav>
```

js

```
$(function() {
    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({auto:true});

    $("#toggle").toggle(function(){
        $(".mainNav ul").slideDown();
    }, function(){
        $(".mainNav ul").slideUp();
    });


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your toggle method is toggling `#toggle`, the function you pass to toggle, is a function to callback once toggle animation is complete http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

it's better to use SlideToggle for this,

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {
  $('.mainNav ul').slideToggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```